# fixed size window in figure MATLAB

Tags: matlab, size, textures

I have a program to do in my memory and i really need your helps.

My question is about : how can i have a 64x64 window around a pixel 
in my figure image on MATLAB.

Because i want to select a pixel (just one pixel) in my image, then when i click on this pixel, my program take the others neighbor pixel.

What i want to say is : the pixel that I have to select it is only to create a 64x64 window around it automatically.
I need this to complete my analyze of texture MRI image.

If some one can not understand I'm here to explain more
and I'm sorry for my English if it's not clear.

Comment: Do you need to click multiple points and get multiple 64x64 samples?

Comment: No i need to click just once , but when i click on this pixel (point) in my image , the program take also the other neighbor pixel in the limit of widow 64*64

Comment: What If you're using a 64x64 there is no center pixel since it's even So where would you "center" this matrix if I click on a pixel? Do you want the raw pixel values or is interpolation ok?

Comment: yes i need a centre pixel , but i think it's must a 65*65 window is not it ?

Comment: i need the syntax , how make this on MATLAB

Comment: any answers any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clear all
close all
clc
bitmap=uigetfile('*.*');
I = imread(bitmap);
figure, imshow(I)
[x,y]=ginput(1);
%[Nx,Ny] = size(I(round(y)-5:round(y)+5,round(x)-5:round(x)+5));
%I1=I(round(y(1)),round(x(1)));
myMask = I(x-32:x+32,y-32:y+32);
[ D ] = sfta( myMask, 1);    

so what do you think about my code ?
```